# Fluent XML translation using dynamic type

Tags: c#, xml, dynamic

Based on Kevin Hazzard's posting here; http://blogs.captechconsulting.com/blog/kevin-hazzard/fluent-xml-parsing-using-cs-dynamic-type-part-1
I'm trying to use the logic. Basically what this is supposed to do is take a piece of XML and convert it into an object you can use. E.g. say my xml is;

```
<someObject>
    <Name>Timmy</Name>
</someObject>
```

I'd like to be able to do;

```
dynamic obj = Converter(xmlText);
string name obj.Name;
```

After much Googling, I came across Kevin's blog and post for a `DynamicXml` object that should do the job but I cannot get it to work (or I'm not using it correctly). My understanding of .NET's `Expando` object is limited and I have no code sample to go on bar the blog post. I've collated Kevin's two posts on the subject into a single object which is;

```
public class DynamicXml : DynamicObject, IEnumerable
{
    private readonly List<XElement> _elements;

    public DynamicXml(string text)
    {
        var doc = XDocument.Parse(text);
        _elements = new List<XElement> { doc.Root };
    }

    protected DynamicXml(XElement element)
    {
        _elements = new List<XElement> { element };
    }

    protected DynamicXml(IEnumerable<XElement> elements)
    {
        _elements = new List<XElement>(elements);
    }

    public override bool TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder, out object result)
    {
        result = null;

        // handle the Value and Count special cases
        if (binder.Name == "Value")
        {
            result = _elements[0].Value;
        }
        else if (binder.Name == "Count")
        {
            result = _elements.Count;
        }
        else
        {
            // try to find a named attribute first
            var attr = _elements[0].Attribute(XName.Get(binder.Name));
            if (attr != null)
            {
                // if a named attribute was found, return that NON-dynamic object
                result = attr;
            }
            else
            {
                // find the named descendants 
                var items = _elements.Descendants(
                    XName.Get(binder.Name));
                if (items != null && items.Count() > 0)
                {
                    // prepare a new dynamic object with the list of found descendants
                    result = new DynamicXml(items);
                }
            }
        }

        if (result == null)
        {
            // not found, create a new element here 
            _elements[0].AddFirst(new XElement(binder.Name));
            result = new DynamicXml(_elements[0].Descendants().First());
        }
        return true;
    }

    public override bool TrySetMember(SetMemberBinder binder, object value)
    {
        if (binder.Name == "Value")
        {
            /* the Value property is the only one that may be modified. TryGetMember actually
                creates new XML elements in this implementation */
            _elements[0].Value = value.ToString();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public override bool TryGetIndex(GetIndexBinder binder, object[] indexes, out object result)
    {
        int ndx = (int)indexes[0];
        result = new DynamicXml(_elements[ndx]);
        return true;
    }

    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        foreach (var element in _elements)
            yield return new DynamicXml(element);
    }
}
```

My usage is;

```
dynamic payload = new DynamicXml(PayloadData);
Name = payload.Name;    // error thrown here
```

The exception is;

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'MyProject.Common.Exchange.DynamicXml' to 'string'
```

When I inspect the object, it seems to be a nested series of `DynamicXml` - which from looking at the internals of the code seems right. So I'm left wonder how I actually get at the value `Name`? According to the blog it should just be `payload.Name`. Thoughts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You missed one very important thing: you can call the node by name but you must de-reference it's value because the getMember is always returning a DynamicXml object.

try:

```
payload.Name.Value
```